# Strings and unordered_map running slow

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map, istream

Here is 2 functions in my code that are running REALLY SLOW. 
Basically i read in a document name, open the document, then process it one word at a time. I need to split up the document into sentences, and give each sentence a hash table that represents the number of times the word appears in the sentence.  I also need to keep track of all the new words, and a hash table for the total document.

When i run my code now on 10 documents, that have a total of 8000word, and 2100 uniq words it takes about 8000+ seconds to run... almost 1 second per word.

can you tell me how long `if(istream.good())` should take?

Or, if you can tell when what is delaying my code.  Please let me know if a section is not clear, i will help.

P.S. You can see in the code where i have a `start = clock()` and `end = clock()` commented it constantly returns < 1ms.  And that is mind-boggleing

```
void  DocProcess::indexString(string sentenceString, hash * sent){

stringstream iss;

string word;
iss.clear();
iss << sentenceString;

while(iss.good())
{

    iss >> word;
    word = formatWord(word);

    std::unordered_map<std::string,int>::const_iterator IsNewWord = words.find(word);

    if(IsNewWord == words.end())
    {
        std::pair<std::string,int> newWordPair (word,0);
        std::pair<std::string,int> newWordPairPlusOne (word,1);

        words.insert(newWordPair);
        sent->insert(newWordPairPlusOne);
    }
    else
    {
        std::pair<std::string,int> newWordPairPlusOne (word,1);
        sent->insert(newWordPairPlusOne);
    }
}
```

}
void DocProcess::indexFile(string iFileName){

```
hash newDocHash;
hash newSentHash;
scoreAndInfo sentenceScore;
scoreAndInfo dummy;

fstream iFile;
fstream dFile;
string word;
string newDoc;
string fullDoc;
int minSentenceLength = 5;
int docNumber = 1;
int runningLength = 0;
int ProcessedWords = 0;
stringstream iss;

iFile.open(iFileName.c_str());

if(iFile.is_open())
{
    while(iFile.good())
    {
        iFile >> newDoc;
        dFile.open(newDoc.c_str());
        DocNames.push_back(newDoc);

        if(dFile.is_open())
        {
            scoreAndInfo documentScore;
            //iss << dFile.rdbuf();
            while(dFile.good())
            {
                //start = clock();
                dFile >> word;
                ++ProcessedWords;

                std::unordered_map<std::string,int>::const_iterator IsStopWord = stopWords.find(word);


                if(runningLength >= minSentenceLength && IsStopWord != stopWords.end() || word[word.length()-1] == '.')
                {

                    /* word is in the stop list, process the string*/
                    documentScore.second.second.append(" "+word);
                    sentenceScore.second.second.append(" "+word);

                    indexString(sentenceScore.second.second, &sentenceScore.second.first);

                    sentenceScore.first=0.0;
                    SentList.push_back(sentenceScore);
                    sentenceScore.second.first.clear(); //Clear hash
                    sentenceScore.second.second.clear(); // clear string
                    //sentenceScore = dummy;
                    runningLength = 0;
                }
                else
                {
                    ++runningLength;
                    sentenceScore.second.second.append(" "+word);
                    documentScore.second.second.append(" "+word);

                }
                //end = clock();
                    system("cls");
                    cout    << "Processing doc number: " << docNumber << endl
                        << "New Word count: " << words.size() << endl
                        << "Total words: " << ProcessedWords << endl;
                        //<< "Last process time****: " << double(diffclock(end,start)) << " ms"<< endl;

            }
            indexString(documentScore.second.second, &documentScore.second.first);
            documentScore.first=0.0;
            DocList.push_back(documentScore);
            dFile.close();
            //iss.clear();
            //documentScore = dummy;
            ++docNumber;
            //end = clock();
            system("cls");
            cout    << "Processing doc number: " << docNumber << endl
                << "Word count: " << words.size();
                //<< "Last process time: " << double(diffclock(end,start)) << " ms"<< endl;

        }
    }

    iFile.close();
}
else{ cout << "Unable to open index file: "<<endl <<iFileName << endl;}
```

}
`

Comment: Instead of `while(iss.good())`, you could just do `while (iss >> word)`

Comment: Try specifying an initial size for your hash so it doesn't have to resize - if you are expecting ~8000 unique entries, create maybe 10,000 buckets. Also, try switching the hash to a normal std::map, see if your performance improves significantly. If so, the issue is with your usage of the hash table. If not, it's somewhere else.

Comment: i guess i should have let you know.  hash is defined as     `#define hash std::unordered_map<std::string, int>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try it without

```
                system("cls");
```

in any of the loops?  That surely isn't helping, it's an expensive call.

Comment: I tried all of the comments at the same time, and something solved the problem.  Not 100% sure what it was but its running faster now!! WOOT

Comment: Just check by putting the system call back in and that was FOR SURE the problem.  Is there anyways to clear the cmd fast?

Answer (score 0):

To clear the screen quickly, instead of `system("cls");`, try `cout << '\f';`.

Comment: I have found that the best way is you use printf () with .\r for replacement